# Calling multiple functions before a command in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm attempting to run multiple, distinct functions before running a command in a cog from my bot. I have multiple sets of functions that should run, with some being different enough that a single function would not be preferable. My first thought was to simply use `discord.ext.commands.before_invoke` multiple times on a command like so:

```py
from myFunctions import function1, function2
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.before_invoke(function1)
    @commands.before_invoke(function2)
    async def myCommand(self, ctx):
        pass
```

Unfortunately, in this code the only function that would be called before is `function1`, as it replaces the hook for `function2`.

Is there a native way in Discord.py to run multiple functions before a command?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, could you make a function that calls the two functions in sequence and set *it* as the hook?

Comment: @SilvioMayoloI was trying to say that I have many different groupings of functions, so if I had to do it that way I would have to create a grouping for every set of them. I know I could do it that way, but was hoping for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

### Running Functions In ORDER:

Just put them inside another function:

```
from myFunctions import function1, function2
from discord.ext import commands
from functools import partial

async def fcaller(fs, *args):
    for f in fs:
        f(*args)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.before_invoke(partial(fcaller, [function1, function2]))
    async def myCommand(self, ctx):
        pass
```

### Running Function At THE SAME TIME:

```
from myFunctions import function1, function2
from discord.ext import commands
from threading import Thread
from functools import partial

async def fcaller(fs, *args):
    threads = []
    for f in fs:
       threads.append(Thread(target=f, args=args))
    
    for t in threads:
       t.start()
    
    for t in threads:
       t.join()

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.before_invoke(partial(fcaller, [function1, function2]))
    async def myCommand(self, ctx):
        pass
```

### EDIT

Changed it for a universal function caller after reading the comments

Comment: So I need to make a function for every distinct grouping I have?

Comment: Also there is the problem that the before_invoke will pass two arguments (instance and context) to the functions.how would you go about passing those using your method?

Comment: Done please check it

Comment: Also fcaller would need to be async to work in before_invoke. Unfortunately, this only confirms my fears of how I would have to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem ?

Comment: Actually, after doing some testing I found that the use of functools.partial is NOT compatible with before_invoke. It must directly be an async function passed to it. Alternatively you could fix this by doing a wrapper function call (a function that takes the functions as an argument and then returns a function that takes instance and ctx). Please correct this answer or I'll have to unaccept it.